# How to increase performance of serialization and deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization

I found many similar questions on this site but some of them confused me.

Someone answered that Externalization was better than Serialization since jdk 1.3 since java reflection were very slow till that version. Afterward using Serializable could be a good option since they are automatic too (In some special condition we need to call readResolve() etc)

But this [benchmarking report](http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking) depicts that externalizable is best for serialization, even with latest version of java, than any other API serializer.

I searched for many examples for readObject() and writeObject(). And i found that they are not doing anything special. One of the example is given below;

```
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) 
{
   try
   {
      out.writeInt(number);
      out.writeInt(accNumber);            
      out.writeObject(name);
      out.writeObject(handle);
      out.writeObject(addrString);
      out.writeInt(paidTime);
      out.writeByte(callsLeftToday);
    :
   }
   catch(Exception all)
   {
   }
}
```

**Edit**
My question is about how to write readObject() and writeObject() or readExternal() and writeExternal() fro better performance.

Comment: Please read the following article and attempt to write some code.  If you get stuck, come back here and ask a specific question about where you are stuck. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Comment: Your edit didn't make things any clearer.  Are you asking which is faster?  Profile both methods and find out yourself.

Comment: Externalizable is faster as per benchmarking report I linked. My question is about how its method readExternal(), writeExternal() etc improve performance

Comment: You can improve the performance by writing the fields in a fixed order with assumed data types.  writeObject and writeExternalizable support this. Externalizable uses some reflection, and for maximum performance you can avoid using it at all. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/10/serialization-using-bytebuffer-and.html